# AJAX page redirect properly. But because of redirect the passed data going to refresh

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am performing a ajax request but ajax request working fine. but the problem is after the request i am performing a page redirect. Because of previously passed variable values are going to reset. Following is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/UserCreater/UserCreatorSub.jsp",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"subuserId":subuserId},


        success: function(){
            debugger;
            window.location.replace("/UserCreater/UserCreatorSub.jsp");
        }
      });
```

Page is calling 2 times. Thats the problem .

Comment: You don;t want to refresh page? Remove window.location.replace... line

Comment: Then how can i redirect to that page? @MichalToldy

Comment: By form if you want to use post method? <form action="/UserCreater/UserCreatorSub.jsp" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="subuserId" value="something" /></form> and then just calling something like form.submit()

Answer (score 0):

Since the Response code of the Request is 302, the Browser automatically redirect to the url in the response irrespective of the location you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of Ajax is to avoid page redirections/refresh (most of the time). You may want a simple request instead, since you're redirecting on the very same page.